# How Do I make a circle shape of these 2pt lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, path, pathfinder

Hi i Have a group of 2pt lines, and above it I have a circle.

[image]

I want to make a Circle out of the lines, heres a rough paint drawing of what i mean:

[image]

how Can I cut the lines, so they form a circle like this, and anything outside of the circle is chopped off?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have lines like this -

[image]

I created a circle and send it back - Shift+Cmd+[,

[image]

Next I expand the shapes and perform Minus Front in Pathfinder.

This is the result -

[image]